# Cannot execute ls command in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker compose to run my services. But for some reason I'm not able to call e.g. this command 'ls -la /home'. It gives me an error:

> Cannot start service test: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc >create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "ls /home": stat ls /home: no such >file or directory: unknown

whereas when I use just 'ls' then I see all the directories... what's wrong?

Below is my  docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mqtt_broker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./
    network_mode: host
  test:
    depends_on: [ mqtt_broker ]
    image: ubuntu:22.04
    command:
      - ls -la /home
    network_mode: host
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your command with the array notation (just like in [Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)), so that it is properly joined together as one, instead of different parts being interpreted separately.

```
command: [ "ls", "-la", "/home" ]
```

To run multiple commands,

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -lah; whoami; hostname"]
```

But as the comments pointed out, as this increases complexity,  consider running a script instead.

Comment: You're right... Is there a way to let's say separate this commands? Suppose that I would like to call two commands, first: chmod +x /home/my-exe and then /home/my_exe --opt. When I put all this "parts" of my command in the array, then it says: chmod: unrecognized option --opt

Comment: @bielu000, if you want a command that can run multiple other commands, that's what shells are for.

Comment: You could also `RUN chmod ...` in your Dockerfile, so that you don't need to repeat that setup step every time you run a new container.

Comment: @bielu000you could wrap it in a bash.  `command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -lah; whoami; hostname"]`  but the other comment is right, if you're venturing into multiple commands, consider running a script.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command `"ls -la /home"`. There is command `ls` that takes `-la` argument and `/home` argument.

```
command:
  - ls
  - "-la"
  - /home
```

Or alternatively, docker-compose will do the splitting if you pass a string instead of an array (consult YAML specification):

```
command: "ls -la /home"
```

Or just:

```
command: ls -la /home
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be a missing $PATH problem -- does the following work?

```
command:
  - /bin/ls -la /home
```

Comment: This is trying to run an executable named `home ` in a directory named `ls -la` (plus a space on the end) that is itself a subdirectory of `/bin`